# Не работает отправка клонированной формы и кнопка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Создаю клон формы через jQuery. У клона не работает отправка, и не нажимается кнопка "Отмена", которая должна удалить форму. И перестает работать автовысота текстового блока:

```js
$(".js-comment_field").each(function () {
  this.setAttribute("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px; overflow-y:hidden;");
 }).on("input", function () {
  this.style.height = "21px";
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
 });
  
$(".js-comment_field").on("input keyup", function(event){
  if($(this).val() != "") {
   $(".js-comment_button").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
   $(".js-comment_button").prop("disabled", true);
  }
 });
  
 $(".js-comment_field").click(function(){
  $(".js-comment-buttons").show();
 });

 $(".js-cansel_button").click(function(){
  $(".js-comment_field").val("");
  $(".js-comment_button").prop("disabled", true);
  $(".js-comment_field").css("height", "21px")
 });
  
  
  
  /* копирование формы */
  
  var form_id = 0;

 $(".js-copy").click(function(){
  var id = "comment_form_" + form_id++;
  $(".js-comment_form").clone().appendTo("body").attr("id", id);
  $("#"+id).find(".js-comment-buttons").show();
  $("#"+id).find(".js-cansel_button").addClass("js-close_form").removeClass("js-cansel_button");
  $("#"+id).find(".js-comment_field").focus();
  $("#"+id).find(".js-comment_button").text("Ответить");
 });
```

```css
.comment_form .field_block {
 margin: 0 0 6px;
 padding: 0 0 1px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 position: relative;
}

.comment_form .field {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 0 4px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 25px;
 border: none;
 background: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 21px;
 color: #0d0d0d;
 outline: none;
 resize: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

.comment_form .field_block .line {
 width: 0%;
 height: 2px;
 background: #000;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
}

.comment_form .field:focus + .line {
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 left: 0;
}

.comment_form .comment_buttons_block {
 display: none;
 font-size: 0;
 line-height: 0;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 text-align: right;
}

.comment_form .comment_button {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 10px 16px;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 17px;
 letter-spacing: normal;
 color: #606060;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.comment_form button.comment_button {
 margin: 0 0 0 8px;
 border: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background: #065fd4;
 font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

.comment_form button.comment_button:disabled {
 background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="comment_form js-comment_form" action="#">
<div class="field_block">
  <textarea class="field js-comment_field" name="comment" placeholder="Оставьте комментарий"></textarea>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<div class="comment_buttons_block js-comment-buttons">
  <div class="comment_button cansel_button js-cansel_button">Отмена</div>
  <button class="comment_button js-comment_button" disabled>Оставить комментарий</button>
</div>
</form>


<br><br><br><br>
<div class="js-copy">Копировать</div>
```

Comment: В клоне вы удаляете класс с кнопки "отмена" //removeClass("js-cansel_button");// А очистка формы у вас именно по этому классу работает: $(".js-cansel_button").click(function(){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("input keyup", ".js-comment_field", function(event) {
```

Аналогично - другие события для динамически создаваемых элементов.

```js
function adjustHeight() {
  $(".js-comment_field").each(function() {
    this.setAttribute("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px; overflow-y:hidden;");
  }).on("input", function() {
    this.style.height = "21px";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
  });
}

$(document).on("input keyup", ".js-comment_field", function(event) {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $(".js-comment_button").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $(".js-comment_button").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});

$(document).on("click", ".js-comment_field", function() {
  $(".js-comment-buttons").show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".js-cansel_button", function() {
  $(".js-comment_field").val("");
  $(".js-comment_button").prop("disabled", true);
  $(".js-comment_field").css("height", "21px")
});

/* копирование формы */

var form_id = 0;

$(".js-copy").click(function() {
  var id = "comment_form_" + form_id++;
  $(".js-comment_form").clone().appendTo("body").attr("id", id);
  $("#" + id).find(".js-comment-buttons").show();
  //$("#" + id).find(".js-cansel_button").addClass("js-close_form").removeClass("js-cansel_button");
  $("#" + id).find(".js-comment_field").focus();
  $("#" + id).find(".js-comment_button").text("Ответить");
  adjustHeight();
});
```

```css
.comment_form .field_block {
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 0 0 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  position: relative;
}

.comment_form .field {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.comment_form .field_block .line {
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.comment_form .field:focus+.line {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  left: 0;
}

.comment_form .comment_buttons_block {
  display: none;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-align: right;
}

.comment_form .comment_button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #606060;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.comment_form button.comment_button {
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #065fd4;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.comment_form button.comment_button:disabled {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="comment_form js-comment_form" action="#">
  <div class="field_block">
    <textarea class="field js-comment_field" name="comment" placeholder="Оставьте комментарий"></textarea>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment_buttons_block js-comment-buttons">
    <div class="comment_button cansel_button js-cansel_button">Отмена</div>
    <button class="comment_button js-comment_button" disabled>Оставить комментарий</button>
  </div>
</form>


<br><br><br><br>
<div class="js-copy">Копировать</div>
```

Comment: А можно на примере аком нибудь?